Understanding COM Errors with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on Different Build Platforms in .NET Framework 4.7.2
I have .net framework 4.7.2 project which is using that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel nuget which is giving error in Office 2021 version.
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND)).

I’ve found that repairing Office resolves the issue, but I want to understand why this error occurs on different build platforms without office repair.
Environment Details:
OS: 64-bit
Office: 64-bit (without repair)
Behavior Observed:
When the build platform is set to x64, I get a COM exception. When set to x86 or Any CPU (with Prefer32Bit set to False), there is no error.
Here’s my question: Why does the error occur specifically with the x64 build platform, while it doesn’t occur with x86 or Any CPU (without Prefer32Bit set to True)?

This is a long stand issue (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/exception-from-hresult-0x8002802b/1f940438-b24d-4857-92d4-778182ce50d3). Only Microsoft can tell you with certainty why/when/how it happens or not.
